# java: multidimensional generic array creation

Tags: java, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array

How do I make a multidimensional array of generic items in java?

Consider the class:

```
class A<T>
  {
    T t;
    public A(T t) { this.t = t; }
  }
```

When I try to create a multidimensional array:

```
A<String>[][] array = new A<String>[2][3];
```

I get the following error:

```
generic array creation
A<String>[][] array = new A<String>[2][3];
                      ^
```

I tried the following:

```
A<String>[][] array = (A<String>[][]) (new Object[2]3]);
```

But that just throws: `java.lang.ClassCastException`

What's the fix?

(I anticipate people recommending to use lists. Please explain how to achieve this using arrays.)

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865946/error-generic-array-creation .

Comment: What is your reason for insisting on arrays rather than other collection types?

Comment: You are casting an Object[][] to an A<String>[][], the 2 are not compatible.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan -- Arrays are easier to index than lists. `array[i][j]` is more legible than `array.get(i).get(j)`. When you're coding a complex algorithm, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do something like this

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    A<String>[][] array = (A<String>[][]) Array.newInstance(new A<String>("dummy").getClass(), 2, 3);
```

**EDIT:**

from @dsg's suggestion the following skips the creation of a temporary object.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    A<String>[][] array = (A<String>[][]) Array.newInstance(A.class, 2, 3);
```

or (from @irreputable's suggestion)

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 A<String>[][] array = new A[2][3];
```

Comment: I believe the following also works: `    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    A<String>[][] array = (A<String>[][]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(A.class,2,3);`

Comment: @dsg You guys are extremely funny. `Array.newInstance(A.class, 2, 3)` is exactly the same as `new A[2][3]`

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an array of type-specific generic in simple way.

```
List<String>[] list = new List<String>[2]; //Illegal
List<?> aa[] = new List<?>[2]; // OK
...
A<?>[][] array = new A<?>[2][3]; // OK
A[0][0] = new A<String>(...);
```

This is an interesting article about Java 1.5 generics, "[Java theory and practice: Generics gotchas](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html)"

Comment: This is cool! I suppose you can do `A<String>[][] array = (A<String>[][]) new A<?>[2][3];`

Comment: yeah, but in this way you'll have unchecked cast warning, to prevent it add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I was able to piece together a solution.

As we saw, `A<String>[][] array = new A<String>[2][3];` does not work.

Here how to construct a `2x3` array of `A<String>` objects that does work:

```
// get the class of the basic object
Class c = new A<String>("t").getClass();

// get the class of the inner array
A<String>[] a0 = (A<String>[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(c, 0);

// construct the outer array
A<String>[][] array = (A<String>[][]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(a0.getClass(), 2); 

// fill it with instances of the inner array
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++ i)
{   
  array[i] = (A<String>[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(c, 3); 
}
```

A much cleaner version (Thanks, @Balla R):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
A<String>[][] array = (A<String>[][]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(A.class,2,3);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the class of the basic object without instantiating it?

Comment: While I'm glad you figured this out, the burning question is still why go to all this trouble over using `ArrayList<ArrayList<A<String>>>` ?

Comment: no, that's the problem. Before you instantiate it, there's not a way to determine its type. See my answer, you can use `A<?>[][]` for your array.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this: (non-generic)

```
String[][] non_generic_array = new String[][];
```

And make a utility class to implement the functions you made in `A<T>` (as I suppose there are). Eg:

When you had this in `A`:

```
public class A<T>
{
    T obj;
    public A(T obj) { this.obj = obj; }

    public void someFunction() { ... }
}
```

You can make a utility class:

```
public class AUtils
{

    public static <T> void someFunction(T obj)
    {
        // Here your code, applied to obj
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`new A[][]` and cast it to `A<String>[][]`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I thought Java Arrays (as of Java 6) didn't support generics. One of my biggest "wtf" when I started programming with generics in java.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A<T> 
{
    T s;

    public A(T t)
    {
        s = t;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return s.getClass().toString();
    }

    public T getThing()
    {
        return s;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    A<?>[][] a = new A<?>[2][3];
    a[0][1] = new A<String>("hi");

    System.out.println(a[0][1].getType());
    System.out.println(a[0][1].getThing());

    A<String> b = (A<String>) a[0][1];
}
```

output:

> class java.lang.String
>
> hi