# What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, stack

When I run the following code:

```
class MyStack<T>
{
    private T[] stack;
    ... private T top;
    private static final int size=50;

    public MyStack()
    {
      stack = new int[size];
      top = 0;
    } 
}
```

I get this error

```
MyStack.java:18: generic array creation

stack = new T[size];
...
1 error
```

What should the proper code be, so I dont get this error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Generic Array Creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865946/error-generic-array-creation)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot instantiate a parameterized type in Java. and thus also not create arrays of it. Replace `T[]` by `Object[]` and create it as `new Object[]` and use casts against `T` in the methods whenever necessary.

Only if Java had [Reified generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927789/why-should-i-care-that-java-doesnt-have-reified-generics), it would be possible.

Comment: I'd start to take a look in source code of `java.util.Stack`.

Comment: Nah, better look at ArrayList. The Stack class is only a subclass of Vector, so we don't even see the array there.

Comment: @Paulo: `ArrayList` isn't a stack. An `ArrayDeque` would be better, but that's pretty complicated for a student. Also if OP knows basic Java, he should understand what `class Stack extends Vector` means and in any IDE you should be able to (Ctrl)click just `Vector` to see its source code.