# What are generic arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a code, whose MCVE is like this

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Test
{
    LinkedList<Node>[] arr;

    Test(){
        arr = new LinkedList<Node>[4];
    }

    public static void main(){
    }
}

class Node{   
}
```

where I get this error

```
error: generic array creation
        arr = new LinkedList<Node>[4];
              ^
```

I looked for the error and found these two posts
[How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/529085/3395716)
and [Error: Generic Array Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3865946/3395716)

But I don't understand what a generic array is. I guess(from what I get from the two posts) it means array that does not know what type it's going to store, but in my case the array is specified to be of `LinkedList<Node>` type.

Can someone explain the concept?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18581313/303810), especially **What about creating an array of type List<String>[]?** part

Comment: @JoeClay What's wrong with `LinkedList<Node>[]`? How do you know OP doesn't intend to have an array of lists?

Comment: @JoeClay I don't get what you mean. arr is an array of linkedlists of nodes. So `new LinkedList<Node>[4]` seems correct to me. Wont removing the brackets create only a single linkedlist of nodes?

Comment: Ah, I couldn't tell from your question whether you were getting the syntax mixed up or whether you actually intended to have an array of lists. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/18581313/303810

Since it is a bit large, I'll sum up the relevant part here.

`LinkedList<Node>[]` is a generic array as it has generic type of the component. The problem with this consruct is that you could do the following:

```
LinkedList<Node>[] listsOfNodes = new LinkedList<Node>[1];
Object[] items = listsOfNodes;
items[0] = new LinkedList<String>();
```

So at this point `listsOfNodes[0]` which should have had the type `LinkedList<Node>` would be an instance of `LinkedList<String>`.