# Creating an array of a custom class

Tags: java, class

I have created a custom class called ObjectContainer, and am trying to create an array containing those objects. However, when i try to instantiate the array with `new ObjectContainer[initialCapacity];`
it gives me Generic Array creation error. I thus found an answer online that suggests casting an object to it, which i have done

```java
(ObjectContainer[]) new Object[initialCapacity];
```

However, i now get another error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [LHashSet$ObjectContainer;
> ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> [LHashSet$ObjectContainer; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

What do i do to create an ObjectContainer array?

Edit:
Using

```
(ObjectContainer[]) new ObjectContainer[initialCapacity];
```

Gives me Generic array creation error.

ObjectContainer class:

```
private class ObjectContainer extends Object {
    String object;
    private ObjectContainer(String object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
```

This is implemented within a HashSet class:

```
public class HashSet<T> implements MultiSet<T>, Iterable<T> {
private ObjectContainer hashTable[];
public LinkedMultiHashSet(int initialCapacity) {

       hashTable = (ObjectContainer[]) new ObjectContainer[initialCapacity];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```java
(ObjectContainer[]) new Object[initialCapacity];
```

by

```java
new ObjectContainer[initialCapacity];
```

as `Object` cannot be cast to `ObjectContainer`

*EDIT 1 :*
With provided class, the following code does compile

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ObjectContainer[] containers = new ObjectContainer[3];
    }
}

class ObjectContainer extends Object {
    String object;

    private ObjectContainer(String object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 :
The following code does compile

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ObjectContainer[] containers = new ObjectContainer[3];
    }
}

class ObjectContainer extends Object {
    String object;

    private ObjectContainer(String object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}

interface MultiSet<T> {}
class LinkedMultiHashSet<T> implements MultiSet<T>, Iterable<T> {
    private ObjectContainer hashTable[];
    public LinkedMultiHashSet(int initialCapacity) {
        hashTable = new ObjectContainer[initialCapacity];
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it gives me an error "Generic Array creation" and does not let me perform that

Comment: I think that post might answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865946/error-generic-array-creation

Comment: The post tells me to Cast an Object into ObjectContainer, which results in my original error listed before

Comment: You should provide ObjectContainer class (or library providing that class)

Comment: You should specifiy type in diamond operator during initialization.
Without `ObjectContainer` class in the post, it's hard to determine the source of your problem

Comment: I have added object container class within the post, ObjectContainer is a class within another class.

Comment: Where do you try to create such Array ?
Using a simple implementation does work for me without any compilation error. I uploaded my own version with your class and it does compile

Comment: public class LinkedMultiHashSet<T> implements MultiSet<T>, Iterable<T> {
private ObjectContainer hashTable[];
public LinkedMultiHashSet(int initialCapacity) {

       hashTable = (ObjectContainer[]) new ObjectContainer[initialCapacity];
    }
}

Comment: Provide that information in your post, with implementation and details

Comment: Can you provided your error and stacktrace, it does compile for me : check EDIT 2

Comment: Also do you import your custom class, your code might use one from library which is generic, your class isn't generic

Comment: It has been solved sorry, i created the class within the HashSet Class which was fixed once it was created outside of it