# Cannot find symbol of written method java.util.function

Tags: java, arrays, functor, function-object

I have code like

```
public class Functionz {
    public static boolean test() {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function[] funcs = new Function[] {test}; // and others
        for (Function func : funcs) {
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

and my error is: `cannot find symbol: test` in the line with the function array declaration.

Hope this isn't a stupid question, very new to java, not new to object oriented languages like python and C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Function` in Java does takes one parameter as input and one as output.
You might declare parameter's type this way : `Function<Integer, String>` is a function that transforms an `Integer` into a `String`
Your method `test()` does not take any input value and outputs a `boolean` so it's a `Supplier`.

```java
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {
    public static boolean test() {
        System.out.println("lorem ipsum");
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier[] funcs = new Supplier[] {Main::test}; // and others
        for (Supplier func : funcs) {
            func.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Your code would compile if test requires one (and only one parameter) like

```java
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    public static boolean test(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function[] funcs = new Function[] {(Object anyObject) -> test(anyObject.toString())}; // and others
        for (Function func : funcs) {
            func.apply("lorem ipsum");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the [list of those types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)
Please note that `Function` doesn't type its parameters in construction because [you can't create arrays with generic type in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3866251/11825162) (you might for specific usecases) => Use a `List` will help you here